# How do we project from camera to lidar coordinate when both of the sensors share same coordinate systems?

Tags: object-detection, camera-calibration, coordinate-systems, projection-matrix, kitti

I am working on object detection task. I am able to detect objects in kitti point cloud. I am trying to use the same code on my own point cloud dataset. In Kitti dataset the camera and lidar sensor share different coordinate systems. I have attached image here for reference. For camera the axis are (z,x,y) and for lidar the axis are (x,y,z).

[image: KITTI sensor setup]

For KITTI dataset they have also provided calibration information. I am able to understand the projection matrix for KITTI dataset.I went through few materials.
[Camera-Lidar Projection](https://medium.com/swlh/camera-lidar-projection-navigating-between-2d-and-3d-911c78167a94).

In the above link he has calculated projection matrix as:

```
R_ref2rect_inv = np.linalg.inv(R_ref2rect)
P_cam_ref2velo = np.linalg.inv(velo2cam_ref)
proj_mat = R_ref2rect_inv @ P_cam_ref2velo
```

My question is:
For my dataset the sensor setup is almost same so we can say lidar and camera share the same coordinate system. So, in this case how do I project point from camera to lidar?

In other words,
If my object center is (x=7.5, y=1.7, z=0.58) in camera coordinate system then how do I find the same point in Lidar pointcloud?

Comment: may I recommend a more math-oriented notation that goes like `T_dst_src` to transform from src frame to dst frame, or represent the pose of src relative to the dst frame. then you can be sure you're multiplying the matrices correctly. and you should drop any "_inv" suffix. change the name properly. `T_foo_bar = inv(T_bar_foo)` (bar2foo = inv(foo2bar))

Comment: lidar and camera DO NOT share the same frame. they're related by a rotation at the very least, and some translation too. -- your example point (x=7.5, y=1.7, z=0.58) is very much to the far right and down, extremely out of view of your camera, assuming it's not a fisheye camera.

Comment: Axis for camera in my setup is just like Kitti lidar sensor. x is length(forward direction). y is width and z is height.

Comment: you have a picture. it's got a red triad, green triad, and blue triad. the red and blue one are relevant. their axes don't point the same way. do you see that?